# Is it possible to configure an Angular 6 build to output JS and CSS into separate subdirectories?

Tags: angular, build, production, subdirectory

I have an Angular 6 application.

i am using the `--deploy-url` flag to specify a CDN for all assets, JS and CSS (including thankfully the paths to embedded images in my style sheets).

This is excellent and would suffice except for the fact that my server admin requires that my JS and CSS live in their own respective subdirectories.

So I simply want to configure an Angular 6 build to output those files as instructed.

For example:

```
dist/index.html
dist/js/runtime.js
dist/js/*.chunk.js
dist/css/styles.css
```

etc...

seemingly so simple... yet, this not possible?!

I have searched exhaustively for a solution to no avail.

The only solution i could come up with would be to use a task manager to start modifying the compiled files.

For example, modify `runtime.js` to inject the trailing `/js/` subdirectory  to my CDN url that was initially injected via the `--deploy-flag`, including other necessary modifications elsewhere.

I would really like to avoid having to take this approach, but i am out of time, and i may not have a choice.